Clash between babel and mathptmx
This is similar to what was asked:
Italic Cyrillic in Times
I'm using both babel and mathptmx, and it seems mathptmx changes the font settings for english and mathematical expressions. While I would like to preserve this change for them, it affects my hebrew text. Specifically, it sets the font to be (likely, times new roman?) a font that has no bold or italic in hebrew.
I'm looking for a way to make mathptmx affect only english text and mathematical expressions, while not affecting any hebrew text. Tried to look at cjhebrew, but couldn't find a possible way to change the font there.
Using regular latex on overleaf, not luatex or xetex. I also tried replacing mathptmx with newtxtext,newtxmath, but the same repeats, as it seems these packages simply split the role of changing the font definitions to "only englis"h and to "only mathematical expressions". As said, I'm just looking for a way to avoid the change they have on hebrew (or, maybe in general, on texts from other languages).
Also, I'm not using polyglossia due to other compatibility issues with packages, so trying to stick to babel.
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, hebrew]{babel}
%Workaround for babel and amsthm
\makeatletter
\let\everypar\o@everypar
\makeatother % End of workaround for babel and amsthm
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}


\title{\R{כותרת של מסמך}}
\author{\R{המחבר}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{\R{כותרת}}
\R{כאן מופיע טקסט רגיל}

\R{\textit{כאן מופיע טקסט אלכסוני}}

\selectlanguage{english}
\section{Section}

From here and on, the text is in English. As we all know: $a^{2} \geq 0$ if $a\in \mathbb{N}$.


\end{document}

Results in:

However, after removing the line \usepackage{mathptmx}:

As you can note, the difference is in the second line in the hebrew text, which is now italic. I believe the difference is because mathptmx changes the font for the entire file to times, and hebrew in times has no italic or bold face. I want to preserve the effects of mathptmx on english and mathematical expressions, but not to have it affect the hebrew text.
I tried replacing mathptmx in newtxtext,newtxmath, but the same issue happens.

do not use mathptmx, it is outdated. And you really should use lualatex with hebrew (you can continue to use babel).  Apart from this: you should always show a small but complete example that demonstrates your problem.

That whole first section is typographically wrong too. It’s setting the text R-L, but the paragraphs are L-R. It hurts my brain to look at it and I’ve got the Hebrew skills of a 12-year-old preparing for his bar mitzvah.

@DonHosek This was just for the example, in my full document I've aligned it properly.
